# postgres - fetch latest record of every group

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are three tables `tpr, eptpr, epdss` with the following columns:

```
tpr  : id, tenant_id, provision_status('success', 'failed'), modify_date
eptpr: id, tenant_id, external_product_id, tenant_provision_request_id, unification_source
epdss: id, tenant_id, external_product_id, status, modified_date
```

For every `tpr` there is an entry in `eptpr` i.e. there is one to one relationship between `tpr` and `eptpr` where `eptpr.tenant_provision_request_id` maps to `tpr.id`. `epdss` connects to the `eptpr` only through `tenant_id` and `external_product_id`.

I need to find the following:

** The `epdss` records with maximum `modified_date` for every combination of `tenant_id` and `external_product_id` present in `epdss` only if the latest `provision_status` for the selected combination of `tenant_id` and `external_product_id` in `eptpr` is in `'success'` state. (Note: the `provision_status` is kept in `tpr` table.)**

Now I have created a query to do this but I don't think I have done this in an optimal manner. Can you please help me improve this query further ?

The query is :

```
select epdss2.id from epdss epdss2 
  inner join eptpr on eptpr.external_product_id = epdss2.external_product_id and eptpr.tenant_id = epdss2.tenant_id 
  inner join tpr tpr2 on eptpr.tenant_provision_request_id = tpr2.id and tpr2.id and 0 = (select count(distinct(modify_date)) from tpr tpri where tpri.modify_date > tpr2.modify_date and tpr2.tenant_id = tpri.tenant_id)
  )
where 
  0 = (select count(distinct(modified_date)) from epdss epdssi where epdssi.modified_date > epdss2.modified_date and epdss2.external_product_id = epdssi.external_product_id and epdss2.tenant_id = epdssi.tenant_id)
  and tpr2.provisioning_status = 'success' and eptpr.unification_source = 'source1' and (epdss2.status = 'INPROGRESS' or epdss2.status = 'RETRY' )
) order by epdss2.modified_date asc for update of epdss2 skip locked limit 10
```

I had done this using window functions too but couldn't use that query as it turns out that we cannot get locks when fetching data using window functions like `partition by`.

Comment: A SELECT query will not acquire any locks other than those that prevent DDL against that table. And the use of window functions will not change that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated the query to include select for update - "for update of epdss2 "